# Changing json in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a `json` file called by `fetch` request that looks like this:

```
[
{
    "type": "1",
    "Info": {
        "id": {
            "Id": "123456"
        },
        "total": 1100000
    }
},
{
    "type": "2",
    "Infos": [
        {
            "id": {
                "Id": "105254"
            },
            "total": 142854739
        },
        {
            "id": {
                "Id": "105255"
            },
            "total": 112854739
        },
        {
            "id": {
                "Id": "105256"
            },
            "total": 132854739
        },
        {
            "id": {
                "Id": "106540"
            },
            "total": 122868818
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I find object with type 1 and add it to object which type 2 by this code :

```
  const type1 = Maindata.find(({ type }) => type === '1');
  const MergedData= Maindata.map(item => item.type === '1' ? item : { ...type1, ...item });
```

I want `MergedData` will be included just the objects of `Infos` array.How can I do this?when I get `console.log(MergedData.length)` ,the length of `MergedData` is `2` but I want the length of `MergedData` be `4` , the numbers of objects of `Infos` array.

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        library: null,
        perPage: 20,
        currentPage: 1,
        maxPage: null,

    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/json.bc', {
        method: 'get',
    })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            const Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
            const type1  = Maindata.find(({ type }) => type === '1');
            const MergedData= Maindata.map(item => item.type === '1' ? item : { ...type1, ...item });
            const MergedData2 = MergedData.map(item => item.type === '1' ? item : {...item.hotels}); /// Here I write this code to show just the objects of Infoes array///////
            this.setState(state => ({
                ...state,
                data: MergedData2
            }), () => {
                this.reorganiseLibrary()
            })
        }).catch(error => console.error(error))

}

reorganiseLibrary = () => {
    const { perPage, data } = this.state;
    let library = data;
    library = _.chunk(library, perPage);
    this.setState({
        library,
        currentPage: 1,
        maxPage: library.length === 0 ? 1 : library.length
    })
}

// Previous Page
previousPage = event => {
    this.setState({
        currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1
    })
}
// Next Page 
nextPage = event => {
    this.setState({
        currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1
    })
}

// handle per page
handlePerPage = (evt) =>
    this.setState({
        perPage: evt.target.value
    }, () => this.reorganiseLibrary());

// handle render of library
renderLibrary = () => {
    const { library, currentPage } = this.state;
    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
        return <div>NOResult</div>
    }
    return library[currentPage - 1].map((item, i) => (
        <div className="Wrapper">{this.renderInfo(item)}</div>
    ))
}

renderInfo(element) {
    let len = element.Infos.length
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        return element.Infos[i].total
    }
}

render() {
    const { library, currentPage, perPage, maxPage } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderLibrary()}
            <ul id="page-numbers">
                <li className="nexprevPage">
                    {currentPage !== 1 && (
                        <button onClick={this.previousPage}><span className="fa-backward"></span></button>
                    )}
                </li>
                <li className="controlsPage activeCnt">{this.state.currentPage}</li>
                <li className="restControls">...</li>
                <li className="controlsPage">{this.state.maxPage}</li>
                <li className="nexprevPage">
                    {(currentPage < maxPage) && (
                        <button onClick={this.nextPage}><span className="fa-forward"></span></button>
                    )}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = [
{
    "type": "1",
    "Info": {
        "id": {
            "Id": "123456"
        },
        "total": 1100000
    }
},
{
    "type": "2",
    "Infos": [
        {
            "id": {
                "Id": "105254"
            },
            "total": 142854739
        },
        {
            "id": {
                "Id": "105255"
            },
            "total": 112854739
        },
        {
            "id": {
                "Id": "105256"
            },
            "total": 132854739
        },
        {
            "id": {
                "Id": "106540"
            },
            "total": 122868818
        }
    ]
}
]

var m = s.map(i => Object.keys(i).includes('Infos') ? i.Infos : i.Info)
console.log(m)
```

```
printed Value - [{"id":{"Id":"123456"},"total":1100000},[{"id":{"Id":"105254"},"total":142854739},{"id":{"Id":"105255"},"total":112854739},{"id":{"Id":"105256"},"total":132854739},{"id":{"Id":"106540"},"total":122868818}]]
```

You can just write this small code for getting mergedData of info/infos of whole array.

If both the object has 'Info' key in them - you can just write
`var m = s.map(i => i.Info)`

Comment: Thanks @Waseem for your answer, but I did not get  what you mean.`Json` is going to be dynamic. The `json` file  you see in my code is just an example to show format of my `jaon`. I Thinks in `MergedData` I should do something like this:

Comment: `const MergedData = Maindata.map(item => item.type === '1' ?
                { ...type1, ...item.infos }
                );`

Comment: The format of condition is like this: `condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse `

Comment: How to say nothing to do in `exprIfTrue` part but in `exprIfFalse` do this: ` { ...type1, ...item.infos }`

Comment: @sahar i think it will work for dynamic json - every array of object should have a particular key which you wanna fetch store it in any new array - if key keep on changing then - it need to fixed from backend 

Can you provide me with codepen for this logic or git repo ? i can check it out